# python socket communication for XML-messages

Tags: python, sockets, communication

Setting: I have a server, that should be able to send and receive XML data. The client connects to the socket and receives the XML from the Server first. Then the client should be able to modify the XML and send it back to the server.

The XML-file gets (in this example) saved as a simple string (so it doesn't matter if it is a String or a XML).

What i have so far:

```
def startServer(port,xml_data):
    print "Starting server, listing to port %d" % port
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("", port))
    s.listen(5)

    while True:
        client, address = s.accept()
        print "Accepted connection from remote client at " + str(address)

        client.send(xml_data)

        client.close()

    s.close()
```

So when the client connets to the server, the xml_data gets sent to the client and connections gets closed then. But that is not what i want: I want to modify the XML (or String) at the client and either send it back or retreive it again from the server. I think a solution would be to put a "data = client.recv(1024)" before the send-method and put all in a Loop. Then i would determine some keywords (e.g. send$, get$) which would be send in the clients message and are used at the server to decide what to do.

It would be something like that (not sure if syntactically valid):

```
def startServer(port,xml_data):
    print "Starting server, listing to port %d" % port
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("", port))
    s.listen(5)

    while True:
        client, address = s.accept()
        print "Accepted connection from remote client at " + str(address)

        client.send(xml_data) #first time, XML gets sent

        while True:

            data = client.recv(1024)

            keyword = data.split("$",1)[0] #split only first "$"
            if keyword == "get": #client wants to get data
                client.send(xml_data)
            elif keyword == "send" #client wants to send data
                received_data =  data.split("$",1)[1]
                #received_data can be used for further processing
            else:
                break

        client.close()

    s.close()
```

So if i have a XML (as a string) and the client wants to send it to the server, i would insert the key at the beginning of the message e.g. send$

Finally, my question: Is that a good approach to go, or would you recommend something different?

Comment: in order to give an opinion about the approach we'll need the big picture, who are the users (clients) of this? how will they be able to edit the XML and send it back?

Comment: ok! the system with the server is an embedded system. I try to edit the configuration remotely using XML. As a first step the client is only able to show the loaded XML in a window and the user can edit this window-content (not user friendly yet). But the thing is, the XML content is handled as a simple string. The connection doesn't need to handle multiple connections, just one Client will connect.

Answer (score 1):

Your splits could be partitions...

Also, TCP sockets reserve the right (they seldom do, but they can!) to split or aggregate your send's and recv's into more or fewer send's and recv's.  This can be a source of hard-to-find bugs on networks under high load or over long network paths.  To contend with this, it's important to loop around your send's and recv's, or use something like http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/bufsock.html

Other than that, and I haven't run your code, your approach seems sound.

Answer (score 1):

if possible, rather than this low level sockets try to use [basic http server](http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html), this will give you better support for requests, like standard http get and http post request (what you called get and send) and access to requests headers etc.

using http get/post will also eliminate that concatenation that currently breaks the xml structure.

you'll then have somethings like:

```
class MyHttpHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        ...

    def do_POST(self):
        ...
```

Comment: as it is a embedded system with an innate webserver (i cannot use this one or deactivate it) i think there will occur problems when i use another webserver?!

Comment: if this is the case I guess you can either add this to current http server or run this one on another port...

Comment: ok, i tried it using the basic http server (using this tutorial: http://pymotw.com/2/BaseHTTPServer/) but i didn't find out any way to change the static message in the do_GET method to a dynamic variable without using a global variable. DO you know a way how to get access to a varbiable here?

Comment: where is the dynamic variable coming from? in your code I see that you return a predefined xml string, if this is the case, can you read the xml from a file like: `self.wfile.write(f.read())`